# Reporting on post 90 days of completion date

Tags: reporting

We are trying to create a report showing Opportunities that have checkbox on their Account 'Was this a Referral?' post 90 days of a date field on the Opp.

I set the report criteria as 'Was this a Referral?' equals True AND we need it to only show Opportunities that have field 'Customer Installation Completed Date' but only show records that have dates greater than 90 days after the Installation Completion Date. 
we cannot figure out how to Report only on Opportunities that are greater than the 90 days from the completion date
[image: Screenshot of Reporting]

Comment: Are you asking a question or checking that what you did so far is right?

Comment: Sorry, Question because we cannot figure out how to Report only on Opportunities that are greater than the 90 days from the completion date

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula field on opportunities and calculate number of days on opportunity. you may need to add this field to the Report type to make it available for reporting. if you did not find this field while creating the report.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula field to capture the date difference between the two relevant fields or a formula field(checkbox) to be checked if the difference between the two relevant fields equals 90 days.

So you can pull out a report with Formula field equals 90 days / Formula(checkbox) equals true.